# Can't hear audio over HDMI

Tags: drivers, 22.04, xorg, hdmi, configuration

At first, Ubuntu 22.04 wasn't detecting an HDMI cable at all. I fixed that by copying `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/nvidia.conf` to `/etc/X11/xorg.conf/nvidia.conf` and editing the file.

My laptop uses both an Intel GPU and a Nvidia GPU. I made the Nvidia the primary GPU and everything worked.

Here is the config:

```
DO NOT EDIT. AUTOMATICALLY GENERATED BY gpu-manager
Section "OutputClass"

     Identifier "nvidia"
     MatchDriver "nvidia-drm"
     Driver "nvidia"
     Option "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration"
     Option "SLI" "Auto"
     Option "BaseMosaic" "on"
     Option "PrimaryGPU" "yes"
EndSection 

Section "ServerLayout"

    Identifier "layout"
    Option "AllowNVIDIAGPUScreens"
    Option "PrimaryGPU" "yes"
EndSection
```

The problem is that I can't hear audio. Do I need to add more lines in the configuration file?

I am testing this on a TV, not a smart one. I think it's a 7 year old TV.

How do I fix the audio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the TV is actually directly connected via hdmi and not an adapter chain that drops the audio (such as DVI).

Likely you also will need to switch the system default audio output from the current default device (motherboard sound card?) to the appropriate HDMI audio device in sound settings.

Note that in the default ubuntu sound configuration, plugging in USB sound cards and headphones automatically switches the default audio device to the new device, and unplugging them doesn't necessarily switch back to the same previous audio device.

Comment: thank you, ill i needed to do was change system default audio output,